# Show folders in document library after a file inside is shared

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

I have a document library with some folders which has unique permissions via AD groups for different departments.

What have I done:
I broke inheritance for each department folder and set access via AD groups.

A user A can only see folders where he has at minimum read permission.

If user B with Edit permission, in another folder where user A has no access, shares a file with user A, user A only can access the file via the link in the mail but cannot see the file in the document library.

Is there a possibility to show user A all needed folders in the library document to get a path to the shared file?

For example:
- User A see the folder Human Resources nut not the folder Purchasing. 
- Now user B from Purchasing department shares a document inside folder Purchasing.
- User A should now see the folder Purchasing in document library and inside of it only the shared document.

Comment: It is not possible OOTB in SharePoint. user A need to have permission on the folder to access the files inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how big your organisation is, but you've mentioned different departments.  I think you need to take a different approach, since you mention setting permissions on folders and then item-level permissions.  You are 'weaving a difficult web' to manage in terms of the permissions and security.

I would suggest you think about creating different Document Libraries and try to manage documents at this level instead of using Folder-level security.

### Reading

- [Folder vs. Library in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/folder-vs-library-sharepoint/)
- [SharePoint Document Library – one or many?](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-document-library-one-many/)

I'm not sure how developed your Sharepoint system is, but if it is quite new, maybe some information about [Information Architecture](https://sharepointmaven.com/difference-between-site-collections-sites-pages-document-libraries-and-folders/) would help?

Comment: Thank you for this perfect links. I have know a better understanding about permission options and I think I have a good way to solve my problem.
I think different document libraries without folders and metadata for filtering is the best way.

Comment: Good, I'm glad the links were useful.